# Vue.js orderBy national characters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

orderBy places national/accented characters at the end

`a b c o u z á č ů ž`

in my language (Czech) correct order should be

`a á b c č o u ů z ž`

any way to make Vue sort like this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the sort mechanism of Javascript with [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and the `locales` parameter.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'o', 'u', 'z', 'á', 'č', 'ů', 'ž'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, 'cz');
});  
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```